# PyQt ScrollArea - Scroll Wheel/two-fingure-scroll-gesture - Doesn't work unless mouse is over the scrollbar

Tags: python, qt4

I have a working PyQt GUI that has a scroll area with some matplotlib plots.
As expected I see a scrollbar on the right side and the bottom of the scroll area.

I am using a MAC
When I move my mouse over the Scroll Bar and then I use the two-finger pan gesture i.e mouse wheel, I see mouse wheel events show up in my widget event handler. But for this to happen I have to have my mouse hovering over the scrollbar itself. It doesn't work if I do it with my mouse inside the scroll area.

I would like to be able control the scroll area(pan left/right/up/down) with the 2 finger PanGesture and scroll up/down left/right when my mouse is inside the Scroll Area.

How can I achieve this in PyQt?